# Docketed New Case - Ready for Examination 3 time

Tags: patent-applications

I was twice rejected from the patent office. Now after a second amendment, I received: "Docketed New Case - Ready for Examination"

What now?

Comment: I edited your grammar, spelling and punctuation. Could you please make your question more specific?

Comment: Have you just filed an RCE ?

Answer (score 1):

After two rejections, you most likely did need to file an RCE (Request for Continued Examination)to keep the examination of the application proceeding. If you filed an RCE the bureaucracy dockets this to the examiner as a "new case" even though it isn't actually a new case.